# C2679 binary '-=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have created a Vector class that holds 3 parameters and overloaded the -= operator

```
template <class T>
class Static3Vector
    {
    public:
        Static3Vector() : m_coords{ 0, 0, 0 } {}
        Static3Vector(T x, T y, T z) : m_coords{ x, y, z } {}

        T operator [] (const size_t& i) { return m_coords[i]; }
        T operator [] (const size_t& i) const { return m_coords[i]; }

        Static3Vector operator -= (const Static3Vector& rhs)    
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(m_coords) / sizeof(m_coords[0]); i++) 
             this[i] -= rhs[i];
          return *this; 
        }
    private:
        T m_coords[3];
    };
```

but when I try using this operator

```
Static3Vector<int> vec1(1,2,3);
Static3Vector<int> vec2(1,2,3);
vec1 -= vec2;
```

I get the error I typed out in the title.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a pointer and `this[i]` is not doing what you expect. It takes `this` and performs pointer arithmetic. The only value of `i` that is not UB is then `0` and type of this expression is `Static3Vector<T>`

It is pretty much equivalent to this:

```
Static3Vector<int> vec1(1,2,3);
Static3Vector<int>* ptr = &vec1;
ptr[0]; //ok, equivalent to *ptr
ptr[1]; //compiles, but invokes UB
```

You can solve it in a couple of ways:

```
(*this)[i] -= rhs[i]; //dereference first
this->operator[](i) -= rhs[i]; //call operator explicitly
m_coords[i] -= rhs[i]; //don't use overloaded operator, use data directly
```

---

One more thing: First two will not work with your current implementation, because your `operator[]` returns a copy of the value it stores. It's more typical for `operator[]` to return a reference to stored object:

```
    T& operator [] (const size_t& i) { return m_coords[i]; }
    const T& operator [] (const size_t& i) const { return m_coords[i]; }
```

See also [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your indexing-operators:

```
T operator [] (const size_t& i) { return m_coords[i]; }
T operator [] (const size_t& i) const { return m_coords[i]; }
```

The only difference between them is that one is called for constant objects, begging the question why you duplicated them at all.

That is easily answered though:
Both should return references, the latter `const`-qualified, to avoid copies and allow modification for the first one.

Fix that as a first step to resolving your error.

---

As a second step, recognize that `this` was introduced before references existed, and is thus a *pointer* to the instance, not a *reference*, thus `this[n]` is pointer-arithmetic, not calling your custom indexing-operator. Thankfully that results in a different type and thus failed overload-resolution.

Answer (score 0):

there is incorrect use of the subscript operator. In the operator definitions as for example in this

```
    Static3Vector operator -= (const Static3Vector& rhs)    
    {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(m_coords) / sizeof(m_coords[0]); i++) 
         this[i] -= rhs[i];
      return *this; 
    }
```

in this statement

```
         this[i] -= rhs[i];
```

there is used the b built-in subscript operator for an object of the pointer type `Static3Vector *`.

You need to write

```
         ( * this )[i] -= rhs[i];
```

or

```
         this->operator[]( i ) -= rhs[i];
```

Also the return type shall be a referenced type like

```
    T &  operator [] (const size_t& i) { return m_coords[i]; }
    const T & operator [] (const size_t& i) const { return m_coords[i]; }
```

and

```
    Static3Vector & operator -= (const Static3Vector& rhs)    
    {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(m_coords) / sizeof(m_coords[0]); i++) 
         ( *this )[i] -= rhs[i];
      return *this; 
    }
```

Comment: Isn`t const Static3Vector & operator -= (const Static3Vector& rhs) const being called for const objects? why would I want to subtract from a const object?

Comment: @SzymonO It was a typo. I forgot that it is a compound assignment operator. I though that it is the minus operator.:)